# xamarin forms socketioclientdotnet

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, socket.io

I'm not sure if this is a Visual Studio issue or a genuine incompatibility but trying to install SocketIoClientDotNet into a Xamarin forms PCL project I get

Could not install package 'SocketIoClientDotNet 1.0.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The project targets .NetFramework 4.5 which seems to be supported by the package - what could be going wrong here?

Comment: try installing it to the platform specific projects of the solution, not the PCL. And then try to invoke the methods inside a platform specific project

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the following packages in your **.Droid** and **.iOS** projects (and not in the "common" project):

- EngineIoClientDotNet (v.0.9.22)
- SocketIoClientDotNet (v.0.9.13)
- WebSocket4Net (v.0.14.1)

These versions of packages were the stablest 6 months ago when I had to use sockets in my project. If you want more information don't hesitate to ask me!